# Implement an Ellipse Structural Element

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, rotation, ellipse

I want to implement the following using **OpenCV** (I'll post my attempt at the bottom of the post). I am aware that OpenCV has a function for something like this, but I want to try to write my own.

In an image (Mat) (the coordinate system is at the top left, since it is an image) of width `width` and height `height`, I want to display a **filled** ellipsewith the following properties:

- it should be centered at `(width/2, height/2)`
- the image should be binary, so the points corresponding to the ellipse should have a value of 1 and others should be 0
- the ellipse should be rotated by `angle` radians around the origin (or degrees, this does not matter all that much, I can convert)
- ellipse: semi-major axis parameter is `a` and semi-minor axis parameter is `b` and these two parameters also represent the size of these axes in the picture, so "no matter" the `width` and `height`, the ellipse should have a major axis of size `2*a` and a minor axis of size `2*b`

Ok, so I've found an equation similar to this (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/434482/403961) for my purpose. My code is as follows.. it does seem to do pretty well on the rotation side, but, sadly, depending on the rotation angle, the SIZE (major axis, not sure about the minor) visibly increases/decreases, which is not normal, since I want it to have the same size, independent of the rotation angle.

**NOTE** The biggest size is seemingly achieved when the angle is 45 or -45 degrees and the smallest for angles like -90, 0, 90.

Code:

```
inline double sqr(double x)
{
    return x * x;
}

Mat ellipticalElement(double a, double b, double angle, int width, int height)
{
    // just to make sure I don't use some bad values for my parameters
    assert(2 * a < width);
    assert(2 * b < height);

    Mat element = Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC1);

    Point center(width / 2, height / 2);
    for(int x = 0 ; x < width ; x++)
        for(int y = 0 ; y < height ; y++)
        {
            if (sqr((x - center.x) * cos(angle) - (y - center.y) * sin(angle)) / sqr(a) + sqr((x - center.x) * sin(angle) - (y - center.y) * cos(angle)) / sqr(b) <= 1)
                element.at<uchar>(y, x) = 1;
        }

    return element;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pesky typo sneaked in your inequality. The first summand must be

```
sqr((x - center.x) * cos(angle) + (y - center.y) * sin(angle)) / sqr(a)
```

Note the **plus** sign instead of **minus**.

Comment: Yaaay, seems to work very well now. Thank you so much! I actually remember I may have thought I found it strange there's no plus in there (now that I think of it better, the 2D rotation matrix only had one minus in one of the cells), but in the book where I read the formula, it was written with a minus (I guess it was a typo). It seems to be well written in the Stackoverflow post I mentioned though :) Thank you once again for your help!

Comment: Must have been a typo. In case the rotation angle equals π/4, a (0;0) point, for instance, would always make the whole left side of the inequality small (or even zero in case h == k) and always fulfill the condition. Thats why the program would yield something rectangle-like when given π/4. Glad I helped!